# JavaScript. Convert user input of MM-DD-YYYY to DD-MM-YYYY using substrings and indexof

Tags: javascript, eclipse, indexof, substring

Okay so I need to write a program where the user inputs MM-DD-YYYY and the program spits out the date rearranged like this DD-MM-YYYY. I have been told to use substrings and indexOf but I have no clue on how to incorporate these two together to get the output I want. 
ex)

input: April 11, 2016
output: 11 April 2016

Comment: You have an input format specified of MM-DD-YYYY but example input of April 11, 2016. Which one is it?

Comment: You might start by finding out what [*String.prototype.indexOf*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) and [*String.prototype.substring*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring) do, and how to use them.

Answer (score 0):

You can use indexOf/lastIndexOf to find the index of the spaces in your string.  Once you have the index you can use substring to pull out and separate the strings.

Example:

```
var date = "April 11, 2016";
var index = date.indexOf(" ");
var month = date.substring(0, index);
console.log(month); // 'April'
```

That should get you started. Once you have the strings separated you can concatenate them back together in the order you want.

Answer (score 0):

Because I'm lazy, maybe something like:

```
var input = "April 11, 2016";
var arr = input.split(" ");

// get rid of that pesky comma
arr[1] = arr[1].slice(0, -1);

// this is embarrassing but I said I'm lazy!
var output = arr[1] + " " + arr[0] + " " + arr[2];
console.log(output);
```